# Creating object with new Object{}

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Could you please explain how this construction actually works and what does it mean?

```
var newObj = new Object () {
  public String s = "test";
  public int i = 1;
};
```

What's the class of `newObj` and how it was created?

Comment: newObj is an instance of anonymous class that extends Object class.

Comment: This is not Java. It might be JavaScript.

Comment: @user207421 [It compiles fine](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoMwDERn8hUWEwyN1Bn1E6oOjBWDCRFKGgLChqqq@PbUiFbqYp/u3dkeVzz57pHStLTBGTABieCKLsJbZV@TGFnWOroOBkFFzbOL/b0BnHsq92S24gzRPm@th8suQJQ1DMWBf6eOJpCEcrbEefUHXWRwQs67uVVKZv0itoMeF9aTNDnE4viiqZTUpraUPg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of the `newObj` is an Anonymous Inner Class. Here you define this anonymous inner class inside the curly brace `{}`.

> An anonymous inner class can be useful when making an instance of an object with certain “extras” such as overloading methods of a class or interface, without having to actually subclass a class.

Also, the `newObj` reference refers, not to an instance of `Object` but to an instance of an anonymous subclass of `Object`.

Comment: That is the only really interesting part: because of `var`, the compiler can now "track" that you are extending Object, so when you put a new method into that class, you can later invoke it.